# Can I find related/similar artists using the spotify app api?

Tags: spotify

Given an artist, does the Spotify app api provide the ability to get related artists? This would be essentially the same list that is shown in the upper right corner of the artist detail page.
There are several 3rd party apis that provide access to this kind of data (like last.fm or echonest), but I'm wondering if this information is directly available in a spotify app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the previous answer was true at the time it was asked, I wanted to note that this information is now available in the v1.x api - `Artist`'s have a `related` collection, in case others come looking for the same info.

Comment: Although this is the correct answer, I just want to add that you can do this using the Web API as well. We just deployed https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-related-artists/. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

No it does not. You could use echonest api to get similar artists and music.